# Use A and D key to rotate left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does my character is not rotating and animating when I press the A and D keys? I know that the rotation of character is based on the camera. How can I fix my code? I want to use A and D to rotate the character. When I try to run my game and test the movement of my character then when I press the A and D key, it is not animating.

This is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipoyCharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isGrounded;

    //Character Controller
    private float speed;
    private float rotationSpeed = 150.0f;
    private float moveSpeed = 6f;
    private float moveFB, moveLR;

    public float mouseSensitivity;

    Animator animator;

    //Camera Controller
    public Transform playerCamera, character, centerPoint;
    private float mouseX, mouseY, zoomSpeed = 2, mouseYPosition = 1f;
    public float zoom, zoomMin = -2f, zoomMax = -10f;

    //For Jump
    private CharacterController controller;
    private float verticalVelocity;
    public float gravity;
    public float jumpForce;

    void Update() {

        mouseX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");

        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp (mouseY, 0, 60f);
        playerCamera.LookAt (centerPoint);
        centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, mouseX, 0);

        moveFB = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
        moveLR = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;


        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveLR, verticalVelocity, moveFB);
        movement = transform.rotation * movement;
        controller.Move (movement * Time.deltaTime);
        centerPoint.position = new Vector3 (character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0) {
                moveSpeed = 8f;
                Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler (0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
                character.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
                animator.SetBool ("isRunning", true);
            } else if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") < 0) {
                moveSpeed = 4f;
                Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler (0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
                character.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
                animator.SetBool ("isBack", true);
            } else if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") == 0 && Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0) {
                animator.SetBool ("isIdle", true);
            }
        } 

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger ("isOnPickUp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i am overlooking something in your code, but i don't see anything there that is related to the `A` and `D` keys. You could basically also have asked "_Why is my program not doing anything when i press the J key?_" Same answer: There seems to be nothing in your code handling this key...

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Make your program handle the `A` and `D` keys in some way...? (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1373810/how-to-move-the-character-using-wasd.html)

Comment: How? Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you wrote all that code, you should have enough of an idea on how to add A and D to the mix

Comment: Honestly, I found it on youtube tutorial. This what I did: centerPoint.transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 90 * Time.deltaTime, 0); and I removed this line: centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, mouseX, 0); I have centerpoint which the child gameobject is the Main Camera. I can use the a and d key. But is there any solution that I can use the mouseX?

Answer (score 0):

I think its not about your code. In unity, when you want to use a axis like Vertical, or Horizontal, you need to set your axis capture key.

Go to Edit -> Project settings -> Input, and set your Vertical and Horizontal axis properties.